# WebView in SpriteKit

Tags: sprite-kit, wkwebview

Working on MacOS and SpriteKit and looking to add a WKWebView. I would think that you could just add one like so.

```
    webView = WKWebView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height))
    let url = URL(string: "http://www.llbean.com")
    let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    webView.load(request)
    view.addSubview(web)
```

Doing that in the top level ViewController doesn't do anything. Is there a better way to float a WebView above the SKView?

Comment: It's been awhile so I won't use answer, but comment. You basically want an NSView inside an SKScene. It's possible the WK view is just under your scene. Your SKScene is its own view, so in the controller that holds both the SKScene and your WKView, use this function: "BringSubviewToFront" on the WK view. If that doesn't work, you'll have to tinker.

Comment: Doesn't look like that function is available on macOS.

Comment: You can fully use UIKit in SpriteKit, so it would make sense to me that you can use NS stuff for mac. You can make a global reference to your view / window in your GameViewController, and then add Cocoa stuff from anywhere with that, most likely. You can do that on iOS at least :P

Answer (score 0):

This question is at the center of my goal to convert my Game website to an iOS App.

So, I also need to insert my WKWebView into a new empty SKScene and that I do this creation within Xcode’s GameViewController routine loadView(). It is here I need to create my empty SKScene.

And this precisely what I do **not** know how to do.

It’s essential I do this because then I can use

```
myEmptyScene.sceneDidLoad() {
// the above URL code here
   checkGamePadConnection() // my custom method
}
```

The reason I insert the above URL code into the SKScene is that others insist that each SKScene has its own WKWebView, not just the top ViewController.

Until I solve this, I am at a standstill